# Adiciona produto se o mesmo já foi removido

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho um problema neste código: Porque ao invés de adicionar somente um elemento do nada ele pega o que já foi removido e coloca novamente? O erro está nesta listagem do mostraProdutos, pois se dou um alert no nomeproduto ele pega somente o que foi clicado.

```
$(document).on("click",".btn-adicionar-carrinho",function(e){
    // esvaziar o carrinho de compras
    carrinhovazio = $('.car-vazio').empty();
    // id do produto
    var idProduto = $('.nomeproduto').attr("id");
    // nome do produto
    var nomeproduto =  $('.header-ingrediente').text();
    // valor do produto
    var valorproduto = $('.v-lor').text();
    // quantidade do produto
    var quantidadeproduto = $('.item-qtd-produto').text();
    // imagem do produo
    var imagemproduto =  $('.imagemprodseq').data('id-imagem');

    alert(nomeproduto);
    mostraProdutos += "<div class='prodmostra'><div class='imagem-prod' data-id-prod-carrinho=" + idProduto + ">"
    mostraProdutos += "<img class='imagem-carrinho' title='" + nomeproduto + "' src='" + urlBase + "imagem/produto/" +  imagemproduto + "/jpg' alt='Imagem carrinho de compras CloudDelivery' width='100' height='70' />"
    mostraProdutos += "</div><div class='produto'><a href='' style='float: right;' class='excluir-produto-carrinho' title='Retirar produto'>Remover[x]</a><div class='nomeprodutocart'>"+ nomeproduto+ "</div>"
    mostraProdutos += "<div class='qtd-texto'>Quantidade: </div><div class='quantidadeprodutocart'>"+ quantidadeproduto  + "</div><div id='valorprodutocart' class='valorprodutocart'><span>"+ valorproduto +"</span></div></div></div>";
    // mostra os dados do carrinho de compras selecionado

    tabelacarrinho.html(mostraProdutos);

    somaValores();
  });
```

Comment: tenta explicar mais o problema é que assim é dificil

Comment: posta o código onde eliminas o produto

Comment: Eu até entendi o problema e sei resolver, mas falta código ai ! Posta o seu HTML. Em resumo você precisa limpar o HTML do tabelacarrinho e passar os novos valores como você já faz.

Comment: Veja em: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/228358/item-do-carrinho-de-compras-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-removido